# Not able to new create react app by using "npx create-react-app myapp" command

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am getting below error message every time i try to create a new react app. i am new to react so please forgive me if i am making any silly mistake.

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\khedk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at C:\Users\khedk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:383:19
at new Promise ()
at install (C:\Users\khedk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:334:10)
at C:\Users\khedk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:461:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'spawn'
}

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have npm installed on your PC? If not installed it on your pc first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).